# autoSave on LAST KeyUp ONLY JQuery, PHP, MySQL. How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Here's some code I've found that I think is the key to my answer but I haven't been able to fully understand it yet.

[jQuery autoSave v1.0.0](https://github.com/geniuscarrier/autoSave/blob/master/jquery.autoSave.js)

```
/*
 jQuery autoSave v1.0.0 - 2013-04-05
 (c) 2013 Yang Zhao - geniuscarrier.com
 license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.autoSave = function(callback, ms) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var timer = 0, 
                $this = $(this),
                delay = ms || 1000;
            $this.keyup(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                var $context = $this.val();
                if(localStorage) {
                    localStorage.setItem("autoSave", $context);
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    callback();
                }, delay);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Below I have a working sample of what I've researched so far. I want to modify this code so that it triggers on KeyUp instead of simply every so many seconds regardless of user updating or not.

**index.php**

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <h2 align="center">Auto Save Data using Ajax, Jquery, PHP and Mysql</h2>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group"> <label>Enter Post Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="post_title" id="post_title" class="form-control"> </div>
    <div class="form-group"> <label>Enter Post Description</label> <textarea name="post_description" id="post_description" rows="6" class="form-control"></textarea> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" name="publish" class="btn btn-info">Publish</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id">
      <div id="autoSave"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
          function autoSave()  
          {  
               var post_title = $('#post_title').val();  
               var post_description = $('#post_description').val();  
               var post_id = $('#post_id').val();  
               if(post_title != '' && post_description != '')  
               {  
                    $.ajax({  
                         url:"save_post.php",  
                         method:"POST",  
                         data:{postTitle:post_title, postDescription:post_description, postId:post_id},  
                         dataType:"text",  
                         success:function(data)  
                         {  
                              if(data != '')  
                              {  
                                   $('#post_id').val(data);  
                              }  
                              $('#autoSave').text("Post save as draft");  
                              setTimeout(function(){  
                                   $('#autoSave').text('');  
                              }, 5000);  
                         }  
                    });  
               }            
          }  
          setInterval(function(){   
               autoSave();   
               }, 10000);  
     });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**save_post.php**

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("mysqlserver", "database", "password", "databasename");
 if(isset($_POST["postTitle"]) && isset($_POST["postDescription"]))
 {
  $post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["postTitle"]);
  $post_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["postDescription"]);
  if($_POST["postId"] != '')  
  {  
    //update post  
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_post SET post_title = '".$post_title."', post_description = '".$post_description."' WHERE post_id = '".$_POST["postId"]."'";  
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
  }  
  else  
  {  
    //insert post  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(post_title, post_description, post_status) VALUES ('".$post_title."', '".$post_description."', 'draft')";  
    mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
    echo mysqli_insert_id($connect);  
  }
 }  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do these is with what I call a rolling timeout, basically a timeout that gets reset on every key press so something like this, this is a bit psudo ish, but it should give you the idea

```
     var timeout;

     $('body').on('keyup', '.field', function( event ){
          if( timeout )
                clearTimeout(timeout);

          timeout = setTimout( function( event ){
                autosave();
          },400); //i find 400 milliseconds works good

    });

    function autosave(){
         ....
    }
```

So basically what happens is on the first keyup,  we set the timeout.  Then if another key is pressed within `400` milliseconds we cancel the timeout and set a new one.  Once the user stops typing for longer then the timeout, the save function is triggered.

cheers!

clearTimeout

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

setTimeout

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

One other thing you can do to improve this is to store and abort previous ajax (XMLHttpRequest) requests form the save function ( especially if it takes some time to save it )

so in the save function

```
var timeout;
var saveRequest;

$('body').on('keyup', '.field', function( event ){
    if( timeout )
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    if( saveRequest ){
         saveRequest.abort();
         saveRequest = false;
    }

    timeout = setTimout( function( event ){
        autosave();
    },400); //i find 400 milliseconds works good
});


function autoSave(){
      ....
      saveRequest = $.post( url, {}, function( data ){
           ...
      }
       ...
}
```

This works on the same idea, if a request is pending and we get a call for a new request, then the old request doesn't matter, because the data has been updated.  So we can cancel that request and queue up a new one.

XMLHttpRequest.abort()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

I would probably do the first one, well first.  And if it takes long time to do the saving then maybe think about aborting the requests.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't wait to try this! So, to clarify, each instance created within the 400ms mark is destroyed before the next one is created or does it just keep creating new instances with no garbage collection?

Comment: the `clearTimeout( timeout )` will destroy the previous timeout.

Comment: I've accepted your answer and posted my updated working version as an answer for you to see. How would you implement the XMLHttpRequest.abort() in my answer? Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the working version with some extras.**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var timer;

        $('#post_title').keyup(function() {

            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }

            timer = setTimeout(function(event) {
                autoSave();
            }, 1000); //wait 1000 milliseconds before triggering even.

        });

        function autoSave() {
            var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
            var post_title = $('#post_title').val();
            var post_description = $('#post_description').val();
            //if(post_title != '' && post_description != '')  
            if (post_title != '') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "save_post.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        postTitle: post_title,
                        postDescription: post_description,
                        postId: post_id
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data != '') {
                            $('#post_id').val(data);
                        }
                        var time = showTime();
                        $('#autoSave').text("Draft Autosaved " + time).show();
                        $('#autoSave').fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

  function showTime() {

    var timeNow = new Date();
    var hours = timeNow.getHours();
    var minutes = timeNow.getMinutes();
    var seconds = timeNow.getSeconds();
    var timeString = "" + ((hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours);
    timeString += ((minutes < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + minutes;
    timeString += ((seconds < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + seconds;
    timeString += (hours >= 12) ? " P.M." : " A.M.";
    return timeString;

  }
```